# Why does Twitter Bootstrap input validation affect name arguments in Tornado?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, tornado

I am modifying the [Tornado `chatdemo` example](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/).  I copy the example as-is and make two modifications:

1. I add a new input element adjacent to the current input element:

   ```
   <tr>
   <td><input name="body" id="message" style="width:500px"></td>
   <td><input name="bnum"></td>    # <= this is what I added
   <td style="padding-left:5px">
   ```

   (plus the headers:)

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. I add a reference to this in `chatdemo.py` in `MessageNewHandler`:

   ```
   "body": self.get_argument("qname") + ' ' + self.get_argument("bnum"),
   ```

This code works as expected for me—the two strings are concatenated and displayed in the message queue.  What breaks it (oddly) is the addition of Bootstrap form validation.

```
<input name="bnum"  type="number">
```

leads to the runtime error (when submitting the form):

```
400 POST /a/message/new (::1): Missing argument bnum
```

This problem appears with `type="number"` but not `type="text"`.  Any ideas why form validation alters Tornado's ability to extract a name?

- Tornado [`get_argument`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_argument) documentation

Answer (score 0):

This fixes it:

```
str(self.get_argument("bnum"))
```

It makes sense that the value gets returned as a number rather than a string, I suppose, but the error that results is pretty cryptic.